# Replaced Cam Position Sensor, but car still won't start

Tags: hyundai, sonata, cam-position-sensor, p0340

2005 Hyundai Sonata GLS shut off and gave code P0340 after replacing the cam position sensor the car still wont start but the code is gone. The car shut off on my son in the church parking lot. I ran the codes and got a P0340 cam position sensor. After replacing the sensor it still will not start the fuel pump is engaging so I am at a loss. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did any codes come back after replacing the sensor?

Comment: No codes have came back

Comment: Check the basics: Does it have spark? You say you can *hear* the fuel pump, but have you checked the fuel pressure?

Comment: It has good fuel pressure and I am getting injector pulse

Comment: It's getting spark

Comment: What happens when you try to start it? Does it crank?